# Get CUDA_HOME environment path PYTORCH

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, pytorch

I have cuda installed via anaconda on my system which has 2 GPUs which is getting recognized by my python.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
true
```

However when I try to run a model via its C API, I m getting following error:

```
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py in _join_cuda_home(*paths)
722     '''
723     if CUDA_HOME is None:
--> 724         raise EnvironmentError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
725                                'Please set it to your CUDA install root.')
726     return os.path.join(CUDA_HOME, *paths)

OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
```

https://lfd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install_gpu.html page gives instruction to set up CUDA_HOME path if cuda is installed via their method. Since I have installed cuda via anaconda I don't know which path to set.

I tried find method but it is returning me too many paths for cuda. Can somebody help me with the path for CUDA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how exactly did you try to find your install directory?

Comment: @whitespace find / -type d -name cuda 2>/dev/null

Answer (score 12):

Solution to above issue!

As cuda installed through anaconda is not the entire package. Please install cuda drivers manually from Nvidia Website[ https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads ]

After installation of drivers, pytorch would be able to access the cuda path. You can test the cuda path using below sample code. Problem resolved!!!

CHECK INSTALLATION:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('CUDA_PATH'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1
```

Comment: my result: None

Comment: have you installed the cuda toolkit? Please find the link above

Comment: @SajjadAemmi that's mean you haven't install cuda toolkit

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I needed NVCC for flash attention, but it seems that torch uses a reduced version of CUDA libraries. Installing the toolkit from conda forge resolved issue for me

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit-dev -y
```